# React setState with useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have this little visibility changer, and it works flawlessly for changing the attribute of the visibility variable, but my problem is, that it deletes every other variable from "productsState". It shouldn't be keeping the other variables?

```
const listing = () => {
const visibility= !productsState.visibility;
setProdState({visibility : visibility})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState`
> **does not automatically merge update objects**. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object
> spread syntax:
>
> ```
> setState(prevState => {
>   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```

Your code should be updated to use a functional state update and spread in the previous state:

```
const listing = () => {
  setProdState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    visibility: !prevState.visibility,
  }))
}
```

The other answers here that do one of the following are not correctly updating from the previous state (though there may not be any apparent or adverse side-effects):

1. `const visibility= !productsState.visibility;` is toggling from the state of the current render, not the previous state.
2. Some variation of `setProdState({...productsState, visibility : visibility})` as again `productsState` is the state from the render cycle the update is enqueued in, not the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread operators here

```
const listing = () => {
const visibility= !productsState.visibility;
setProdState({...productsState, visibility : visibility})
}
```

Read more about [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

as `productsState` is an object you can spread it when you pass it to `setProdState` or you can use `Object.assign` which has the same effect

```
setProdState({...productsState, visibility: visibility});
```

or

```
setProductState(Object.assign({}, productsState, {visibility: visibility}));
```